# Ч или Ш - как произносить?

Tags: фонетика

Есть ряд русских слов, где порой при произношении Ч заменяется на Ш. Например, "что" - [што]. Тут все понятно и вопросов не вызывает. А вот как быть с такими словами, как "булочная", "коричневый", "яичница"?
Я слышал противоречивые высказывания о том, что замена в этих словах Ч на Ш характерна для определенного говора: одни говорили, что для питерского, другие, что, наоборот, для московского.
Не знаю, где истина, и что говорят об этом нормы русского языка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Кори[чн]евый* по норме произносится без [ш], в остальных случаях возможны оба варианта.

Нашим предкам было неудобно произносить сочетание [чн], [чт] и пр., поэтому произошел процесс дессимиляции, и стали произносить вместо [ч] - [ш]. Сейчас таких трудностей не наблюдается и происходит обратный процесс, когда [ч] вытесняет [ш]. В каких-то словах по прежнему превалирует [ш] (например, [што], в каких-то [ч] (*коричневый*), а где-то, как в *булочной* и *яичнице*, возможны оба варианта.

Если говорить о старых нормах, то "ч" характерно для петербуржской нормы произношения, а "ш" - для старомосковской, но за последние лет 50 они уже так перемешались, что в современной фонетике их выделять уже бессмысленно.

Answer (score 4):

С давних пор существовало разное произношение чн: [шн] в словах бытовых, повседневных и [ч'н] в словах книжных, «высоких».

Еще в XVIII веке орфографическое сочетание чн устойчиво произносилось как [шн], о чем свидетельствуют зафиксированные в словаре Академии Российской (1789-1794) фонетические написания: галстушный, колпашный, копеешный, лавошник, пуговишный, фабришный и др. Однако со временем этот вариант начинает вытесняться произношением [ч'н],

То, что некогда [шн] произносилось значительно шире, чем теперь, видно из укрепления [шн] не только в произношении, но и на письме, например, дото[шн]ый, вместо этимологического доточный, доточен, фамилии Калашников, Кирпишников, Шапошников, Рукавишников, также Столешников переулок в Москве с [шн] вместо чн.

Произношение [шн] характерно для московского говора. Образцовое «старомосковское произношение» выработалось в конце XIX — начале XX веков и присутствует лишь у небольшого числа в основном пожилых людей, а также поддерживается театральной традицией.

Следует иметь в виду, что произношение с сочетание [шн] идет резко на убыль и сейчас сохранилось как обязательное лишь в немногих словах.  В настоящее время произношение [шн]  по старым московским нормам во многих ситуациях приобрело просторечную сниженную стилистическую окраску.Исследования последних лет показали, что [шн] встречается в современном языке все реже и реже (в одних и тех же словах более 80% процентов опрошенных произносят "чн", и лишь менее 20% - "шн").

В современном русском литературном языке на месте орфографического чн произносится [шн], [шн'] в словах коне[шн]о, ску[шн]о, яи[шн']ица, пустя[шн]ый, скворе[шн]ик, праче[шн]ая, горчи[шн']ик, горяче[шн]ый, а также в женских отчествах на –ична: Никити[шн]а, Кузьмини[шн]а, Ильини[шн]а и др. Правильность произношения следует уточнять по орфоэпическому словарю.

http://www.neuch.ru/referat/78914.html

http://www.gramma.ru/ARR/?fnd=2&fl=1&num=1293

Answer (score 2):

Как-то слышал историю про актёра, сумевшего сыграть петербургского чиновника одной фразой: "Ну-с, **ч**то у нас на обед?".
До революции "столичный" говор отличался исключительно "книжным" произношением. И это было характерно не только для России. Просто в большинстве языков именно "столичные" особенности языка закрепляются в качестве "литературных".