# Диссимиляция в русском языке

Tags: недопустимая-метка

В слове "конеЧНо" "ч" меняется на "ш". Можно ли считать это диссимиляцией?

Answer (score 5):

> В слове "конеЧНо" "ч" меняется на "ш". Можно ли считать это
>   диссимиляцией?

[**Здесь**](https://ru.scribd.com/document/322676031/%D0%90-%D0%90-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-2011) *( А. А. Горбачевский "Теория языка", М., 2011)* ― считается. См.:

> **Диссимиляция** (от лат. dissimilatio «расподобление») – фонетическое изменение, когда из двух одинаковых или двух похожих звуков образуются
>   разные или менее похожие звуки. По своим результатам это процесс,
>   обратный ассимиляции.
>
> <...>
>
> Особый случай диссимиляции представляют слова с сочетаниями ***чн***
>   (***конечно***, *скучно* или *вечно, точно, мрачно, беспечно*), в
>   которых буква ***ч*** произносится по-разному. В первых двух примерах
>   – как ***ш***, а в остальных – как ***ч’***.
>
> Диссимиляция ***ч > ш*** здесь вызвана чисто фонетическими причинами.
>
> Осуществлению диссимиляции в последних примерах препятствуют
>   социолингвистические факторы – ориентация на более древнюю
>   орфоэпическую норму, которой после падения редуцированных гласных в
>   течение определенного времени не была свойственна диссимиляция.

.

О диссимиляции ***ч > ш*** в ***конечно*** говорит и *В.Н. Мусатов  ("Русский язык: Фонетика. Фонология. Орфоэпия. Графика. Орфография", М., 2012)*:

> Диссимиляция происходила в сочетаниях согласных [ч’н], [ч’т]. В связи
>   с тем, что [ч’] представляет собой сочетание двух элементов  –
>   смычного [т’] с фрикативным [ш’], расподобление с последующим [н] или
>   [т] по способу образования привело к утрате смычного элемента
>   аффрикаты [ч’], т. е. звука [т’]. Этим обусловлено изменение сочетаний
>   [ч’н] в [шн], а [ч’т] в [шт]:
>
> ***конечно  –  коне[тшн]о  –  коне[шн]о,***
>
> ***что   –  [тшт]о   –  [шт]о***.

Comment: так все же это не диссимиляция?

Comment: Так если "из одинаковых или похожих звуков образуются разные или менее похожие", почему же с ЧН диссимиляция. Что пара Ч и Н, что Ш и Н, — разве это похожие звуки?

Comment: Может быть, так: Н - смычной звук, Ш - фрикативный, Ч - аффрикативный (смычной + фрикативный). В итоге в сочетании ШН похожая смычная часть  звуков Ч и Н исчезла, осталась одна фрикативная составляющая. Звук Ш меньше похож на Н, чем звук Ч, поэтому произошло расподобление (диссимиляция).

Comment: Ха, интересная мысль!

Comment: Но всё-таки хотелось знать, что по этому поводу думает Горбачевский, почему у него ЧН/ШН - это диссимиляция.

Comment: Хотелось **бы**, да?

Answer (score 1):

Чередование ЧН/ШН ― **это произносительная (орфоэпическая) норма**, относится к определенным словам, сравнить: конечный (ЧН) ― конечно (ШН), **не является диссимиляцией.**

**Диссимиляция** ― разуподобление звуков, например:

а) мяг(х)кий, лёг(х)кий, изменение способа образования согласных: К ― смычной, Х ― аффрикативный звук;

б) феврарь (истор.) ― февраль (литер.), колидор (простор.) ― коридор (литер.), замена одного из Р на Л.

[НАУЧНО-ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКОЕ СОДЕРЖАНИЕ МОДУЛЯ | ebooks.grsu.by](http://ebooks.grsu.by/kavinkina_fonetika/nauchno-teoreticheskoe-soderzhanie-modulya-2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Диссимиляция - следствие фонетического закона,обусловленное артикуляцией, а появление разных аллофонов одной фонемы в одинаковых произносительных условиях обусловлено не действием фонетического закона, а регламентацией орфоэпической нормы.

Произношение сочетания чн как шн было широко представлено в старой московской традиции. Эти нормы отразились в указаниях о произношении соответствующих слов в Толковом словаре под ред. проф. Д.Н. Ушакова.
В конце 19 – начале 20 веков многие слова произносились еще с шн, например: булошная, беспроволошный, бутылошный, взятошник, войлошный, молошник, буднишный, бруснишный, бруснишник, беспорядошный и т.д.

По современным нормам такое произношение является устаревшим, в ряде случаев – просторечным. Под влиянием правописания произношение шн постепенно стало вытесняться произношением чн. В современном литературном произношении шн обязательно в немногих словах, в ряде других оно допустимо наряду с чн. В словах нового происхождения, особенно в словах, появившихся в советскую эпоху, произносится только чн, ср.: многостаночный, поточный метод, съемочный.
В современном языке шн произносится в следующих словах: конешно, скушно, яишница, пустяшный, скворешник, прачешная, перешница, в женских отчествах на –ична: Савишна, Ильинишна, Фоминишна.
В ряде слов произношение шн допускается наряду с чн: булошная и булочная, сливошное и сливочное, яшневая и ячневая, молошный и молочный, пшенишный и пшеничный, лавошник и лавочник.

**Из истории.**

На основе диссимиляции и упрощения групп согласных возникло  явление, история которого не закончилась и в наши дни. Это произношение сочетания [чьн]>[тшн]>[шн] (устраняется первый взрывной элемент). Впервые такая замена появляется в памятниках с XIV в., например, в еванг. 1304 г.: клюшникъ < ключьникъ. В памятниках XV-XVI вв. такие сочетания уже обычны, см. в Домострое: пшенишные, грешневая, бруснишная, перешница.

В моск. говоре (и на южных русских территориях) все без исключения сочетания [чьн] после утраты [ь] должны были произноситься [шн]. В северных, цокающих говорах (арханг., новг., костром.), где [ц] и [ч] не различаются (явление цоканья), группа согласных [цьн] (вм. [чьн]) изменилась в [сн], ср.: еисница, пшенисный, молосный, столесник.

А в современном русском литературном языке произношение [шн] почти исчезло.  Сейчас допускается в произношении и було[чн]ая, и все чаще произносят моло[чн]ик, гре[чн]евая. Осталось лишь несколько слов, где [шн] – литературнвя произносительная норма.В чем причины такого **«обратного»** процесса? Причин несколько. Во-первых, это влияние книжной стихии (в старославянском языке ничего подобного не было, и на письме сочетание чн сохранилось); во-вторых, воздействие аналогии, идущее от родственных слов (начало - начну, ночь - ночной, дача - дачный); в-третьих, омонимическое отталкивание, ср.: точный - тошный, точно - тошно, научный - наушный. Правда, и перечисленные причины до конца не объясняют, почему сохраняется произношение типа печной, мучной, речной, ведь это слова бытовые (нет влияния книжной стихии) и нет опасности появления омонимии. Есть точка зрения, что такая неустойчивость произношения [чн] (даже у носителей хорошей литературной нормы) связана с усилением за последние 150-200 лет влияния северной русской нормы, где почти не было произношения [шн] (например, у Ломоносова). ***В современном языке закрепляется произношение [чн], поэтому в новых словах нет сочетания [шн]***: ленточный, поточная, съемочный, многостаночный. Остатком на письме и в произношении является [шн] в фамилиях (Шапошников, Свешников, Калашников, Прянишников) и отчествах (Ильинишна, Фоминишна, Кузьминишна, Лукинишна). А также в словах дотошный (из доточьныи) и двурушник (из двуручный, двуручничать - на жаргоне нищих «пользуясь теснотой в толпе, выставлять обе руки для выпрашивания милостыни»), как термин политического содержания - «человек, который под личиной преданности кому-либо действует в пользу враждебной стороны» - впервые употреблено в словаре Ушакова в1935 г. Ср. также укр. рушник (полотенце).

Comment: Людмила, а откуда вообще взялось произношение ШН, разве здесь нет фонетических причин, связанных с артикуляцией? Этот вопрос уже обсуждался http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38666/Ч-или-Ш-как-произносить. Там  в частности высказана мысль о диссимиляции: раньше было трудно произносить ЧН. Насколько это верно?

Comment: В современности дессимиляции тут действительно нет. А вот раньше была, что подробнее расписано в ответе Славы1947

Comment: Я так думаю, что идёт речь о современном русском, а если о языке 14-15 веков, то да, конечно, это следствие падения редуцированных, как и ассимиляция. Здесь нет места описать всю историю, сейчас добавлю в ответ